# ServerFault DevDays (AdminDays?)... come to Portland, Oregon

Tags: discussion

Since your [rackspace is hosted in Corvallis](http://www.peakinternet.com/business/hosting/?stackoverflow), it only seems appropriate that you should include Oregon on your list of stops for the Serverfault world tour/DevDays-equivalent, whenever you get around to having it. Portland is a beautiful, fun town full of character with a wealth of tech presence including Intel, Tektronix, and IBM, and is a hotbed for open source -- Linus even lives here.

Portland also has a small-town chip on its shoulder for a city its size, which can sometimes come off in a slightly passive-aggressive fashion but means you would be treated as absolute rock stars the whole time you were here.

Comment: I can totally get behind DevDays/AdminDays/whatever in Portland, so long as it can be held on the opposite coast. And by that I mean Portland, Maine of course. :-)

Comment: Apologies for the lack of specificity!  I grew up in New England, you'd think I'd know better.  I'd also settle for an Admin Day in Bah Habah.

Answer (score 2):

Rip city eh?  Just do it in Seatle, they'll come up ;-). Overall a great idea though. Seems like PDX doesn't get the respect it deserves.